# problem in serial communication between PC and ATMEGA 8535(AVR)

Tags: serial, avr

I have written code to send data from controller to pc through serialport using interrupt
but it echos garbage value exactly 3 times back.

```
    ISR(USART_RX_vect)
{
    unsigned char index = UDR;

    UDR = index;        
}

void uartInit()
{
    UCSRA=0x00;
    UCSRB=0x18;
    UCSRC=0x86;
    UBRRH=0x00;
    UBRRL=0x67;
    UCSRB |= (1 << RXCIE); // Enable the USART Receive Complete interrupt (USART_RXC)
    _delay_ms(10);
}

int main(void)
{
    uartInit();
    lcd_init(); 
    sei();

   while(1)
    {
     }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Function used to set baud rate..

```
#define FOSC 16000000// Clock Speed
#define BAUD 9600
#define MYUBRR FOSC/16/BAUD-1


void USART_Init( unsigned int baud )
{
/* Set baud rate */
UBRRH = (unsigned char)(baud>>8);
UBRRL = (unsigned char)baud;
/* Enable receiver and transmitter */
UCSRB = (1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN);
/* Set frame format: 8data, 1stop bit */
UCSRC = (0<<USBS)|(3<<UCSZ0);
}
```

Comment: This frequently a result of the client baud rate being set incorrectly.

Comment: How exactly are you connecting your AVR to the PC? I assume you have a TTL-RS232 tranceiver setup with an IC such as the MAX232. Is that so?

Comment: yes thats how it is connected.

Comment: @DaemonMaker - When there isn't enough information in the question to determine if a suggestion like this is an answer or not, it's probably best making a comment asking for clarification rather than posting a one line answer which may or may not be relevant.

Comment: I appreciate what you are saying @Mark Booth. However I have seen this error enough that I am confident in my answer. I qualify with "frequently" only because it is by no means always the case.

Comment: @DaemonMaker - I agree that there is a possibility that this is the reason and hopefully the edit will provide enough information for someone to answer the question authoritatively.

Comment: @user1551103 What serial settings are you using on your computer?

Comment: I just noticed your macro MY_UBRR, sorry about that. Are you calling USART_Init with baud = MY_UBRR? If so, I'll delete [this answer](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/991/37).

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the UBRR register incorrectly: it should not directly hold the desired baudrate, but a value that depends on your CPU speed (which you defined as the macro FOSC, but never used) and the baudrate. The exact calculation is described in the [ATMega8535 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2502.pdf) (p.147).

See the [AVR UBRR Calculator](http://www.josephn.net/avr/avr_ubrr_calculator) for easy calculation of the proper UBRR register values (note that the calculator assumes U2X = 0, as seen in Table 72, p.173).

**EDIT:** I just noticed your macro MY_UBRR, sorry about that. Are you calling USART_Init with baud = MY_UBRR? If so, I'll delete this answer.

Comment: I've just added your edit as a comment to the question to prompt the questioner to see if we can't resolve this.